# AWS Static Website Hosting: server IP address could not be found, after the site already worked

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

so I've followed the documentation of Amazon's S3 and Route 53 to host a static website.
it worked perfectly and the next day my site was online. I kept updating my index.html afterward with small stuff like extra Text here and there and so far I had no issues, it would every time update the site to reflect the new changes. Until suddenly I visit my website and get a "server IP address could not be found" and I cannot reach my website.

I checked dnschecker.org and internic.net to verify the DNS status of my site, and it showed everything green. I created an Availability test in the Route 53 dashboard and it returns 200 OK.
I also made sure the 4 server names from the Hosted Zone match the ones internic is returning.

so apparently every service says that my site is reachable, but it's not. I have not changed any Public Access options since the first time after I've initially done it using the documentation.
I have also tried reaching the site from a different browser, different PC, and from my phone. they all cannot reach the website.

I absolutely have no idea what to do, to get my site back running. I would very much appreciate some insight.

Footnote: I am very new to this, so please let me know if I need to provide extra information

Comment: Can you share the domain name?  It's difficult to guess at the answer.

Comment: sure! its 8bitjunky.com @stdunbar

Comment: I don't see any issues.  Your IP resolves to 52.219.75.130.  I'm using the DNS servers from Comcast, my U.S. based ISP or using DNS over HTTPS from Cloudflare.  Are you sure your DNS is working right?  The fact that none of your devices can find it makes me think it's a problem perhaps with your home setup.

Comment: @stdunbar that's actually very plausible. I just turned on Data on my phone and the website loaded. I live in Germany in a students dorm using eduroam Internet (college internet). is there a way to kind of "update" my DNS listings? sorry I might be using the wrong terminology here. what's strange is that it already has worked with my home internet

Comment: @stdunbar Thank you very much for the insight, that's already helpful.

Comment: Depending on your O/S you can use the [Google Public DNS servers](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) of 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 instead.  This should bypass anything local.

Answer (score 0):

so it turned out the reason is that I was on the college's Network and somehow my website got delisted from their DNS server (I don't have an exact explanation, just an observation).
my website loaded using Data on my phone and also if I turned on a VPN on my PC. so basically its a DNS problem